# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet of this name

Tags: java, excel

I am getting an exception when inserting more than 1.2 million records. Successfully inserted 1 047 000 records in 1 sheet and when creating the new sheet to insert the rest of the records, I am getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a
>   sheet of this name

I am using this condition for creating the new sheet

```
if(rowCount>1047000){
    wsSheet = createSheet(sheetName, xssfWorkbook);
    createHeader(wsSheet, columsnList, xssfWorkbook, null,listResult.isNameFieldRequired());
    rowCount = 1;
}
```

Tried of changing the `sheetName` in

```
wsSheet = createSheet(sheetName, xssfWorkbook) as sheetName+"1"
```

but still the same exception.

Comment: How long is your `sheetName`? I think it gets truncated at a particular length. Also try some random sheet name say `sheetName = sheetName + System.currentTimeMillis()`.instead of `sheetName+"1" `

Comment: Check existing sheets before creating new one using `workBook.getSheetIndex(sheetName)`. If returned index != -1, check your logic for sheet names.

Answer (score 3):

There is some oddity in the way the `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet` checks if a string is already used as a sheet's name: the candidate name is truncated using name.substring(0, 31) and compared to existing names truncated the same way, so you have to make strings differ in at least a character in this range.

Answer (score 1):

```
XSSFSheet newSheetName = workbook.createSheet("sheetName"+1);
```

That should simply work. Then depending on your code, you may need to increase the newSheetName variable scope.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting 1 you can insert datetime as its trying to add all the record at once so taking the same sheet name.

use the below code for datetime and call it in your code in place of 1

please refer this code for datetime;

============================================================

String dateTime=new Date().toString().replaceAll(":", "_");

wsSheet = createSheet(sheetName, xssfWorkbook) as sheetName+dateTime;

=====================================================================

It should work.

if not work the use datetime with miliseconds

Hope it help